# Jquery (ajax) load function not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am fairly new to JQuery and Ajax functions, and I cannot figure out why my script keeps breaking. I basically have a form where a user inputs their name and location. When the user submits the form, the script uses JQuery's $.post() function to send the user values to "locationHandler.php", which takes the user information(name and location) and stores it in a mysql database. After the $.post request succeeds, I want to use JQuery's .load() function to update the html inside an arbitrary div tag. Every time the form is submitted the script stores the data into the mysql database, as it is intended to do so, however the script fails to .load() my php file.

Here's the code for my index.php page:

```
<?php ?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#locationForm").submit(function() {
            var unameVal = $("#locationForm input[name='uname']").val(); 
            var locationVal = $("#locationForm select[name='location']").val();
            $.post("locationHandler.php", {uname: unameVal, location: locationVal}, function() {
                 $("#display").load("defaultPhp.php");
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="locationForm" method="post">
        <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" />
        <label>Location:</label>
            <select name="location">
                <option value="uncc">UNC Charlotte</option>
                <option value="ncsu">NC State</option>  
            </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="display"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for my defaultPhp.php page, which is located in the same directory as my index.php page:

```
<?php 
     echo "<p>This is some arbitrary text</p>";
?>
```

I have tried removing the `$(document).ready(function(e) { ... });` and putting the script tags directly under the closing `</form>` tag, but then script stops storing the data into mysql database.

So first of all, why if I remove the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` from the above script, will it stop storing values into mysql database?

And second, why won't the script load the content of my defaultPhp.php page into the div tag?

Comment: I suggest you to use $.ajax

Answer (score 2):

Please use **return false** before the end of submit function.

Comment: ^^^^ Wow I feel stupid now haha, oh well its late. Thanks this worked

Answer (score 0):

> So first of all, why if I remove the $(document).ready(function(){...}); from the above script, will it stop storing values into mysql database?

Because javascript does not know your form, until the document is ready

Comment: ^^ Yes but even when I gave the document ample time to load, the script still wouldn't work. I guess I don't understand the importance of wrapping the script in a document ready function

Comment: @Yonny For example: It should work too, if you append your script-section at the end of your body, without document.ready check.
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#locationForm").submit(function() {
            var unameVal = $("#locationForm input[name='uname']").val(); 
            var locationVal = $("#locationForm select[name='location']").val();
            $.post("locationHandler.php", {uname: unameVal, location: locationVal}, function() {
                 $("#display").load("defaultPhp.php");
            });
        });

</script>

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request via `$.post` do not prevent sending page to server by native browser behavior. You must use event `preventDefault` function to cancel it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#locationForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//stop form submiting
        var unameVal = $("#locationForm input[name='uname']").val(); 
        var locationVal = $("#locationForm select[name='location']").val();
        $.post("locationHandler.php", {uname: unameVal, location: locationVal}, function() {
             $("#display").load("defaultPhp.php");
        });
    });
});
```

More info about `preventDefault` [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all..yoyu need not to remove $(document).ready(function(){...}); from your script...also do not remove script tag otherwise your script will stop work...In case of load...Please check wethet the path you given is correct...

e.g. $( "#display" ).load( "ajax/test.php");